# .gitignore files based on their content

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm looking for a way to ignore files in git that have a certain path in their file. These are XML files that are all stored together, but some reference folders that are in .gitignore. I want to exclude the XML files that reference these folders.

Is this possible purely with .gitignore? I can imagine other ways to achieve this, like force keeping these files with a script, but that would not be favorable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Git doesn't allow you to ignore files based on their contents.  That would involve reading every file in your working tree to determine whether it had a particular string, and in many cases, you can have a large number of large generated files, so such an operation would be extremely expensive.  One of the goals of `.gitignore` is to improve performance by not considering files which aren't interesting.

You'll need to adopt another solution, such as putting those files in a single folder or naming them with a certain convention so that you can ignore them with a path-based pattern.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. Though if you were able to mark folders or files with certain extensions, performance could be less of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't quiet understand what you mean by "force keeping these files with a script", so maybe this is the way you do not favor:
I suggest generating a (second) `.gitignore` file via the [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and `git add` the wanted XML files automatically, like:

```
grep -l <referenceToFolderToAvoid_1> <pathToXmls>/*.xml > <pathToXmls>/.gitignore
...
grep -l <referenceToFolderToAvoid_N> <pathToXmls>/*.xml >> <pathToXmls>/.gitignore

git add <pathToXmls>/*.xml
```

Instead of putting all the paths in by hand, the second `.gitignore` file could be generated using the content of your already existing `.gitignore` file.

Comment: What I meant is finding these files via a batch file, in a way you describe. Though I will hook it somewhere else which is relevant for my use case instead of pre-commit. Thanks for your suggestion though!